# It was quick going around the region

Tags: meaning-in-context

it is a quote from the movie ***Ford v. Ferrari***

Ken was going to find a normal job instead of racing cars, Molly is his wife.

> Ken: I'm 45 years old. Do you really think I'm gonna change? I'm never gonna get the good rides. I started too late.
>
> Molly: Because you fought in a bloody war(WW2)! If you stop you'd be bloody insufferable.
>
> Ken: **It was quick going 'round the region.** It's over.

What's the meaning of **It was quick going 'round the region.** here?

Comment: FWIW, [some websites](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=ford-v-ferrari) transcribe it as *It was a quick all around the region*.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But still... What's the meaning of this line in here? A quick?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but it's like *all around the region* is one unit, a compound noun, let's say. So he's saying something to the effect that it was fun going around the region (*a quick all-around-the-region*), participating in these races perhaps, something like that. He's saying it's been fun, but now it's over. Sorry. You'll have to wait for someone more proficient (and you could always place a bounty on this question... it's fine). Perhaps you could isolate the audio clip from the movie and post it somewhere? Then someone else could take a closer ...listen.